# Get TCP window size from Python raw socket sniffer

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpdump

I use the following Python code to catch packets.

```
def main():
    pcap = Pcap('capture.pcap')
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
```

Now how can I get the sniffed packet's window size?.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @chemicalwill I tried passing the packet using the struct model but it didn't work.